# kafka offsets migration from local database to kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

We were trying to upgrade from kafka 0.8 to 0.9 and we would like to use kafka consumer offset management released as part of 0.9. Till now we were storing the offsets on database and wrote our custom consumer which would check for the offsets in the database and fetch messages from kafka.

How could we migrate these offsets to kafka. I have read about kafka offset migration from zookeeper to kafka but haven't found any thing on this.

Answer (score 0):

you can manually send OffsetCommitRequest to kafka to set your current offsets and then start using new consumer. See [kafka wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Committing+and+fetching+consumer+offsets+in+Kafka) for example